# Tensor Product: ONB

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, tensor-products

*This thread is just a note.*

Given Hilbert spaces.

Consider their hilbertian tensor product:
$$\mathcal{H}\hat{\otimes}\mathcal{K}:\quad\langle\varphi\otimes\psi,\varphi'\otimes\psi'\rangle:=\langle\varphi,\varphi'\rangle\langle\psi,\psi'\rangle$$

Then their ONB give rise to an ONB:
$$\mathcal{S}\otimes\mathcal{T}:=\{\sigma\otimes\tau:\sigma\in\mathcal{S},\tau\in\mathcal{T}\}$$
How to prove this circumventing double-series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This answer is community wiki.*

Orthonormality follows immediately:
$$\langle\sigma\otimes\tau,\sigma'\otimes\tau'\rangle=\langle\sigma,\sigma'\rangle\langle\tau,\tau'\rangle=\delta_{\sigma\sigma'}\delta_{\tau\tau'}$$
Totality follows from Parseval's inequality:
$$\sum_{\sigma\tau}|\langle\varphi\otimes\psi,\sigma\otimes\tau\rangle|^2=\sum_\sigma|\langle\varphi,\sigma\rangle|^2\sum_\tau|\langle\psi,\tau\rangle|^2=\|\varphi\|^2\|\psi\|^2=\|\varphi\otimes\psi\|^2$$
But the span of simple tensors is dense.